# Не рисуется объект Java

Tags: java

Не понимаю почему не рисуется прямоугольник в программе (Создается окно с помощью JFrame 700*700)

IntelliJ IDEA говорит метод paint не используется

Есть панель и на ней должен рисоваться прямоугольник

```
package Tutorial;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Player player;
    Timer gameTimer;

    public GamePanel(){

        player = new Player(400,300, this);

        gameTimer = new Timer();
        gameTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                player.set();
                repaint();
            }

        },0,17);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g){

        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D gtd = (Graphics2D) g;

        player.draw(gtd);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

И есть класс Игрок в котором задаются параметры

```
package Tutorial;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Player {

    GamePanel panel;

    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    double xspeed;
    double yspeed;

    Rectangle hitBox;

    boolean keyLeft;
    boolean keyRight;
    boolean keyUp;
    boolean keyDown;


    public Player(int x, int y, GamePanel panel) {

        this.panel = panel;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        width = 50;
        height = 100;

        hitBox = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    }

    public void set() {
        x += xspeed;
        y += yspeed;

        hitBox.x = x;
        hitBox.y = y;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D gtd) {
        gtd.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        gtd.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе paint не правильно указал аргументы

Ниже приведен правильный код

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D gtd = (Graphics2D) g;

        player.draw(gtd);
    }
```